# Evaluate $n^2 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sin \left(2\pi \frac{k}{n}\right)$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: integration, limits, analysis, riemann-sum

I must evaluate
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^2 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sin \left (2\pi \frac{k}{n}\right)$$
It reminds me a Riemann sum, so I'm trying to arrive to that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^2 \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \sin \left (2\pi \frac{k}{n}\right)=\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^3}{2\pi} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{2\pi}{n} \sin \left (2\pi \frac{k}{n}\right)=$$
$$=\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^3}{2\pi}\right) \left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{2\pi}{n} \sin \left (2\pi \frac{k}{n}\right)\right)=\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^3}{2\pi}\right) \int_0^{2\pi} \sin x \text{d}x=\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n^3}{2\pi}\right) \cdot 0=$$
$$=\lim_{n \to \infty} 0 =0$$
But I'm afraid that I can't separate the limit in the product of two limits, even if maybe it is correct because $\frac{n^3}{2\pi} \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$ and the other one tends to the integral (which is a number, but it happens to be $0$; so I don't know if it can be considered as an indeterminate form $\infty \cdot 0$).

Thanks.

Comment: It's an indeterminate.  You could make the same argument as $$1=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot\frac1n=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\cdot0=0$$

Comment: but how did you get the integral of sin(x), from 0 to 2pi?

Comment: Try instead to show that $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{2\pi i\frac kn}=0$ using geometric series, then take the imaginary part.

Comment: @saulspatz: you mean that since the integral is a limit then I can't split the limit of product in products of limits since it is an indeterminate form? I don't get it, because then it would be $\lim_{n \to \infty} n \int_{-1}^{1} x \text{d}x$ indeterminate too but it is $0$; maybe it is just an instance and in general it is indeterminate.

Comment: No, I mean that the theorem that the limit of the product is the product of the limits is only valid when the limits exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of the nth roots of unity is always equal to zero.

$s=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} e^\frac{i2\pi k}{n}=0$

$e^{i\theta}=cos(\theta)+isin(\theta)$

$Im(s)=0 \implies \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} sin(\frac{2\pi k}{n})=0 $

Since the sum is zero for all values of n, the limit is also equal to zero.